# Unknown processes with high CPU utilization Ubuntu on EC2

Tags: server, 18.04, amazon-ec2

I have a Ubuntu instance on EC2 (t3.medium, Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS) that has been consuming lots of CPU. Their names are not Googleable (just random characters) and does not give any clue on what they are. How can I investigate this? Attached is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I tried killing the processes but after a few minutes it will reoccur. Same after a restart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Congratulations! You, good sir, is now the owner of a malware infected server.

It's probably some crypto-currency miner.

Generally they tend to make a entry in your crontab.

To check crontab for the `ubuntu` user, run

```
sudo crontab -e -u ubuntu
```

Remove any unknown entries, but take note of where they pointed to.

After you've updater your crontab, kill all of the processes, and check crontab again. Then remove the files referenced by crontab using `rm`.

Reboot, and verify that it does not reappear. Find whatever vulnerability was used to enter, and make sure **everything** is up to date and secure again, otherwise you'll be reinfected in short order.

I would suggest not doing above, but rather nuking the instance, and starting a new one.

Comment: I stop-started the instance in EC2 console and the problem went away (temporarily). I checked crontab as you mentioned, there isn't anything there (they are all commented).  I will recreate my instance... but how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Keep everything up to date, and secure your box.

Comment: @aol note that things like this *do not* happen due to any inherent vulnerability in EC2 or Ubuntu.  You installed or deployed *something* on this machine with a vulnerability in it, and the vunerability was exploited. It will happen again, and this machine cannot be cleaned -- it must be taken offline immediately and abandoned/destroyed (though you might want to retain snapshots for forensic analysis).  Read [How Do I Deal With a Compromised Server?](https://serverfault.com/a/218011/153161) at Server Fault.

Comment: The only thing i had done with it was install benign things like HDFS and Spark. The security group setting was set to All Traffic from Anywhere -- could this be the cause? In the recreated instance I use All Traffic from my specific IP address -- does this offer better protection?

Comment: update: googled around and it appears allowing connections from anywhere is a bad idea.

Comment: The real solution is to be aware of which traffic you want, and which you don't want, and apply appropriate firewall rules. A web server for instance *wants* connection from anywhere, generally speaking.